# Pyspark IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am attempting to send query results from pyspark.sql to a text file using the pyspark command `saveAsTextFile`

I have tried the following code to achieve this:

```
def main():
#Order by sales descending
example8 = spark.sql("""SELECT
    *
FROM sales_info
ORDER BY Sales DESC""")
print.example8.collect()
example8.saveAsTextFile("juyfd")

main()
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Append ResultsClear Results
  File "<ipython-input-25-ce236630f96f>", line 3
    example8 = spark.sql("""SELECT
           ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

When I indent `example8` I get the following error:

```
Append ResultsClear Results
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-337d9fc099ad> in <module>()
      5 FROM sales_info
      6 ORDER BY Sales DESC""")
----> 7 print.example8.collect()
      8 example8.saveAsTextFile("juyfd")
      9 

AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'example8'
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this error is because the instructions in your *main* function should be indented :

```py
def main():
    #Order by sales descending
    example8 = spark.sql("""SELECT
    *
    FROM sales_info
    ORDER BY Sales DESC""")
    print.example8.collect()
    # Use pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter to save as csv
    # No argument SaveAsTextFile for a DataFrame

    example8.write.csv("path_in_hdfs.csv",sep=';')

main()
```

You could also not use the main function at all, and just run the commands as they appear in your function.

Please note that the path you precise should be a path in the hdfs. You can also precise a separator value for your csv output. For more information : [DataFrameWriter documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter)

Comment: I changed the code to look like the following, without main as you suggested and no indents test3 = spark.sql("""SELECT
  FirstName ,LastName
 ,JobTitle
FROM HumanResources_vEmployeeDepartment
ORDER BY FirstName""")
test3.collect()
test3.saveAsTextFile("/home/packt"). However, I'm now getting the following 
      6 ORDER BY FirstName""")
      7 test3.collect()
----> 8 test3.saveAsTextFile("/home/packt")
--> 964                 "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % 
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'saveAsTextFile'

Comment: you new suggestion appears to work, I specified the following filepath: example8.write.csv("home/packt/Downloads/test8.csv",sep=';') , but the file is placed in the following directly: path file:/home/packt/.vscode/extensions/donjayamanne.jupyter-1.1.4/out/src/common/home/packt/Downloads/test8.csv, but I can't find the file on my Linux box. Any ideas?

Comment: As I mentionned : the file will be in the distributed file system (hdfs). To view it use : `hdfs dfs -ls your_path` And to import it on your local filesystem : use `hdfs dfs -get your_path your_local_path`

Comment: plalanne, while I look for the file can you let me know if the end result will be one .csv file with the result of the query?

Comment: You would rather need to use `hdfs dfs -getmerge your_path your_local_path` to get a unique local csv file. In the hdfs the file is stored in a directory containing multiple files.

Comment: plalanne, I managed to get the file, however there are a number of files - not a single .csv file. I enter the following command: example8.write.csv("/home/packt/Downloads/test13.csv",sep=';'), but I ended up with files starting with part-00000 through to part-00199. Whereas I was hoping for a single file

Comment: hi plalanne, the following worked better for me; example8.coalesce(1).write.csv("/tmp/myresults.csv")